# Keras fit_generator() with generator that extends Sequence is returning more samples than total

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a neural network with Keras. Because of the size of the dataset, I need to use a generator and the fit_generator() method. I am following this tutorial:

https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

However, I prepared a small example to check the samples being fed to the network at each epoch and it seems that the number is higher than the number of samples.

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, files, batch_size=2, dim=(160, 160), n_channels=3,
                 n_classes=2, shuffle=False):
        'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.files = files
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        print ("Number of batches per epoch")
        print(int(np.floor(len(self.files) / self.batch_size)))
        return int(np.floor(len(self.files) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        files_temp = [self.files[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(files_temp)

        return X, y


    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.files))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)


    def __data_generation(self, files_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
        # Initialization
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(files_temp):
            # Store sample
            X[i,] = read_image(ID)

            # Store class
            y[i] = get_label(ID)

        return X, keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)


...

params = {'dim': (160, 160),
              'batch_size': 2,
              'n_classes': 2,
              'n_channels': 3,
              'shuffle': True}


gen_train = DataGenerator(files, **params)
 model.fit_generator(gen_train, steps_per_epoch=ceil(num_samples_train)/batch_size, validation_data=None,
        epochs = 1,  verbose=1,
    callbacks = [tensorboard])
```

Where `read_image` and `get_label` are my methods for getting the data. These methods include a print() for the image being loaded and I get more than I expect. For example:

num_samples = 10
batch_size = 2

Steps per epoch will be equal to 5 and that is what the keras progress bar shows, but I get more images (which I know because of the print inside the method).

I tried debugging, and find that the `__getitem__` function is called more than 5 times! The first five times will have indexes between 0 and 4 (as expected) but then I will get a repeated index and more data being loaded.

Any idea why this is happening? I've debugged down to the data_utils.py in keras but can't find the exact place where index is being passed to `__getitem__`. Everything inside getitem seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, for `steps_per_epoch = 5`, your `__getitem__` will be called 5 times *for each epoch*. So of course, having more than one epoch means it will be called more times then just 5.

Also note that there is parallelism involved, Keras automatically runs your `Sequence` in another thread/process (depending on configuration) so they might be called out of the expected sequence. This is also normal.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I forgot to add I was trying with one epoch... I know the code snipped says more so I will edit. With more epochs, I always get more than number_of_epochs*data_size. When debugging, I can see when it goes to the end of epoch function, so I also know it's called more than expected per epoch.

Comment: @Panda In that case (if true), it would be a bug in Keras.

Comment: I would be more inclined towards a bug in my code tbh. Or is it possible that the getitem function is somehow called (for parallelism reasons) but the data is never passed to the network?

Comment: @Panda No, I don't think so, maybe Keras is just overdoing work and you hit an edge case by using only one epoch (not really common).